# What is Managing Oracle Database Entities?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am doing a project, in which data from every mining site under our company is grabbed by my code and inserted into Oracle database.

How will I monitor the storage space of my database, so as to trigger an email when it is about to run out of storage space?

Comment: Maybe read some documentation about Oracle Database Administrator and then you will be able to query meta-data for retrieving informations you're searching for ! For the email trigger take a look at Java Stored Procedures ...

Comment: Okay, will try reading the documentation.